# Uncaught ReferenceError: <Class> is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, parceljs

I am trying to setup my first webapp with ParcelJS. Everything works in development but when I do a production build my class definitions are not accessible and I get the error:

```
app.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: Class1 is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (app.js:5:24)
    at app.js:9:1
```

I can reproduce the issue with this small example:

```html
<!-- /src/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="./js/class_1.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// /src/jsclass_1.js
class Class1 {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Class1 constructor()");
  }
}
```

```js
// /src/js/app.js
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.class_1 = new Class1();
  }
}

new App();
```

```js
// /package.json
{
  "name": "parcel-test",
  "source": "src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel --public-url ./",
    "build": "parcel build --public-url ./",
    "deploy": "push-dir --dir=dist --branch=gh-pages --cleanup --verbose"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.10.0",
    "push-dir": "^0.4.1"
  }
}
```

I build the app with `yarn build`, and when I go to the `/dist` folder and set up a server with `adsf`, for example, I get the error pasted above.

Here there is a repo with the above code and the parcel setup:

- https://github.com/fguillen/ParcelBugTest

The demo:

- https://fguillen.github.io/ParcelBugTest/

Comment: Why do you import the class in html instead of js when you are using parcel?

Comment: @Konrad because I am new on all this of _modern_ js and I am ignorant. Someone helped me to find the solution and I have added an answer

Answer (score 2):

The scripts get minified separately. What I should do instead is
in the html only import the `app.js`:

```html
<script src="./js/app.js" type="module"></script>
```

and then in my `app.js` class import the other class:

```js
import { Class1 } from "./class_1.js";
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.class_1 = new Class1();
  }
}
```

And `export` the other class:

```js
export class Class1 {
  [...]
}
```

- [Source](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/9316#issuecomment-1764169769)

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `window.Class1 = Class1` but it's a worse option

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't need the multiple script includes in development mode either.